# Project templates Eclipse / Java

Tags: java, eclipse, version-control, maven

I am researching possibilities to create "project templates" for the kind of projects my team is working on (Embedded Java). We want to make it trivial for a new developer to not mess up creating a new project. All the tools we use in our team should be pr

The basic idea is that there should be **one command** to set up a project and IDE to provide for the following:

- Create a new Java project including Eclipse project file.

  Create a Build script (needs to work outside of the IDE).

  Include deploy options in the build script.

  Set up a git project.

  Setup PMD to run with a configured set of rules integrated in the IDE.

  Setup Checkstyle to run with a configured set of rules integrated in the IDE.

  Configure code templates (Eclipse) to match our teams coding guidelines (Javadoc, ...)

  Configure the Eclipse code Formatter.

  The configuration of the command should be upgradeable easily.

So far I see two ways to do this:

- **Maven 2 Archetype**: I basically do not like maven because I have been fighting with it so often. I am not sure that the overhead of trying to make the tool do what I want it to justifies the effort. On the other hand it seems like this is exactly what archetypes are supposed to do. Do you have any experience in how far you can customize the eclipse:eclipse part? I guess that the eclipse configuration with be the most complicated step.

  **Eclipse Nature**: I could create a project nature. As far as I understand the Eclipse Ecosystem that is the component that would show up, if I would choose to provide for something like right click -> New -> My Java Project Type. Do you know how far I can customize the resulting Eclipse project?

  **Shell Script**: I could create an empty project with all the configuration in place, introduce some special tokens in the relevant plain text files (like  and then write a shellscript that reads values for these options from a properties file, copy the project template and substitute the values.). While it is maybe a bit fragile, it seems like a easy and quick way of doing it.

Do give you a little more context: It is ok, if the result locks us into Eclipse. While the build should run without Eclipse (for our CI), the Team uses eclipse and it is highly unlikely that we will ever switch. Also all developers run more or less the same Hard+Software (Linux). We don't work in the domain of Enterprise Java Apps so we really don't need all the fancy dependency management stuff from maven. As a matter of fact our build process is so special, that it probably is much easier to just call make or ant scripts.

So the Questions are:

1. Do you have any experience with this kind of stuff?

   Do you have an opinion towards either the Eclipse Nature way or Maven?

   Do you know other tools that provide for a setup like that?

Thank you very much for your input.

Cheers,
Valentin

PS: People seem to be religious about their build tools. Please note that I do not want to start a flamewar here for or against maven. I am sure maven can be a great tool but I think in our context we only need 5% of its functionality and from my experience that remaining 95% can get in your way.

Comment: Stupid question: Do you create so many projects to justify putting efforts in a generator? Why don't you just checkin everything in your VCS so that a new developer just have to do a checkout?

Comment: Hi Pascal, please don't reflect from your needs on others. I am in an organisation with a lot of developers that start a new project ~ a couple of times per month. Having a tooling that makes it hard for an individual developer to mess up the standard project layout is a good thing and not stupid. Thanks for you time to rant though.

Comment: I'm not reflecting anything on anybody, I'm just asking a question to understand your needs. Please don't reflect from your misconception on others...

Comment: I just reread you answer - sorry I did not see the colon before and read it as a "." so I thought your comment to my question was "Stupid question.". Your question is of course perfectly legit and the answer is "yes it justifies the efforts"... For what it is worth I'm going down the shell script way.

Comment: No problem, I just wanted to clarify the situation (and I think I'll avoid using this formulation in the future to avoid any misunderstanding). And by the way, I thing that the shell script is a good choice here (there is no real point in creating a maven archetypes if you don't use Maven and the Eclipse way will take more time IMHO). Good luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also just create your own PDE tooling project and extend PDE project templates.

There is a great article at IBM DelevoperWorks network that gives a great introduction to [Building templates with the Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment](http://aniszczyk.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/Building-templates-with-the-Eclipse-Plug-in-Development-Environment.pdf)

You can also read up on Eclipse documentation about following PDE extension points:

- [`org.eclipse.pde.ui.templates`](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_pde_ui_templates.html) -- registers plug-in project content templates that are used to generate code for the new extensions
- [`org.eclipse.pde.ui.newExtension`](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_pde_ui_newExtension.html) -- contribute wizards that will be used to create and edit new extensions in PDE plug-in manifest editor
- [`org.eclipse.pde.ui.pluginContent`](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_pde_ui_pluginContent.html) -- provides for contributing wizards that create additional content of the PDE plug-in projects

Comment: In my opinion this is by far the best option. Custom plug-in can achieve pretty much all you mentioned and users just need to install the plug-in and can be updated easily. It takes some time for sure but the end result will be great. The only catch is that you need to know something about Eclipse plug-in development.

Comment: I realize this is over a year old but I am not sure how this was marked the Answer. This functionality only allows you to create plugins that add new _plugin_ templates. It does allow you to arbitrary create any project template.

Comment: Actually, it does. You read too much into the "plugin" part. Most of the project creation wizards (afaik including the Java project creation wizard itself) uses this mechanism to create the basic project file structure, class templates, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you do, for God's sake, don't even think about using the Maven VIRUS for this.  Exception: If you hate yourself, and enjoy inflicting needless pain on yourself and others because you get some kind of sick pleasure out of it--then, you should use Maven. If you also prefer to bleed internally while you work, throw in Ivy.

Eclipse generation IS a good idea (and probably ideal for the end users), but realistically to prevent this turning into such a large project, just go with the simple solution: create a template and use some simple method of customizing it. Just use a find/replace or a simple Python script if really needed. It's hard enough coming up with a complete, solid, re-usable template as it is (a project in itself). Let an Eclipse plug-in or other more automated version come later after you have a better idea of how much work this is.

The find/replace or script method isn't "fragile" since your template is going to be small and written by a single author, not some massive production application with who knows what inside of it. More complex solutions are the ones which tend to really become fragile, not the simple ones.

I think this is a fantastic idea so don't let anyone tell you otherwise, I create templates like this too.

Comment: -1: Obviously a Maven hater.

Comment: Obviously a Maven fanboy?  There is nothing wrong with not recommending Maven when perfectly good and simple alternatives exist.

Comment: As someone apathetic to Maven ... that was extremely funny. :-)

Comment: Well there was some intentional humor interweaved in there for fun. We may in fact try using Maven in a controlled manner, but the "Maven fanboys" attitude of hype (not unlike the Cult of Apple) gets annoying. You have to admit though, it does have some characteristics of a virus. There are projects out there (I think Spring is one of them!) where if you AREN'T a Maven junkie, simply downloading the library becomes a task in itself. Why are we now *forcing* people to adopt a tool, or else have to jump through hoops to get a simple file downloaded?  Maven does not always add value to a project.

Comment: But I think the biggest problem with Maven, and actually many library or tool developers, is that the greatest benefit is derived when developing with an unrestricted Internet connection. There are many developers in secure environments who do not have easy direct access to the Internet. Maven made this old problem (ex. Eclipse update sites which can't be downloaded as an archive) much worse because it continued this ignorant assumption that nobody has any change management or approval processes prior to downloading and using something, and everyone is always connected at all times.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/), it supports the good stuff from Ivy (dependency management), Maven like Archetypes also.

Quick question though... how often do you have to create new projects ?  Is it really that cumbersome that it would define which build system you would use ?

This being said, I do really like to have a standard project structure, saves a lot of time when trying to decide some stupid things that one should not even have to think about...

Comment: Hi,

I know about gradle and I will have a deeper look at it - I didn't know that it supported that archetypes stuff as well. But you are right - I don't want this environment to determine my build system. I think if we would use maven / gradle for this than we would make it call our ant scripts because it is working quite well and has evolved nicely over the last projects...

Thanks for you answer!