# Custom project structure in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I often use a eclipse plugins to quckliy generate project directory structure, for example Spring plugin helps to create WebContent folder to hold WEB-INF contents. But sometimes I create a projects with specific directory structure, always the same. Something like this:

```
[project_name]
-folder1
  -folderA
    -folderX
  -folderB
-folder2
  -dirC
-folder3
```

I know, that I can write my own ant/maven script to generate specific folders, but I don't want to manualy invoke scripts each time after project creating. I want to create a project template which I would use in the future.

What is the best way to create a this feature?

Should I create something like plugin? If yes, how would I do it?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use a plugin or a script to generate the project structure, you're pretty limited.

Since you can create a project from existing source, you could create the folder structure on your filesystem, and whenever you are creating another project, tell Eclipse to "Create Project from existing source" and point it to your template folder.

If you want to write a plugin, you'll want to contribute a `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenProjectWizard` that creates the folder structure as part of the project generation. A good tutorial can be found at: http://cvalcarcel.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/writing-an-eclipse-plug-in-part-1-what-im-going-to-do/%20

Comment: I was thinking about something more sophisticated, because I thought the requirement is to "personalize" the project on creation, but I like this solution as it really does what was asked for

Answer (score 1):

Maven has a concept of project templates called archetypes which is very similar to what you need. It defines the project structure, files, etc and can be customized upon creation.

[image]

If you install the Eclipse m2e maven plugin then you can create a new project from template with a few click

File / new Project / Maven project / Select archetype

[image]

You can use this feature even if you dont want to use maven later. You can auto generate ant scripts or anything like that. You can convert an exisint project into an archetype or create a new one from scratch, desciption is here

http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html

Comment: I know that it's possible by maven, but I wanted to create structure from eclipse without external tools like maven.

Comment: what do you call external tool? The maven plugin has a built in maven you dont need to install anything else just the plugin. You asked in your question if you should create a plugin, the answer is no, there are already a solution for it. The other non maven option is to use PDE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092200/project-templates-eclipse-java

Comment: External tool I named Maven. In basic version of my eclipse there's no maven or ant plugins.

Comment: ok, by default Eclipse does not support this, you will need to download a plugin, may it be the PDE or M2E it is up to you. Both are available in the eclipse marketplace so you dont even need to leave eclipse to do that (neither need to install anything additionally to your operating system like ant or maven)