# Automate Java project creation in Eclipse (by creating a plugin?)

Tags: eclipse, plugins, automation

I would like to automate building a new Java project in Eclipse. Of course, creating a new project is automated for you. What I mean is that I want to automate the creation of packages and certain classes that extend other classes in prexisting outside projects, inside the new project.

Hope that makes sense.

Does anyone know how to do this? Is it feasible? It seems like you would want to use the "Eclipse API" to do what I want to do. I did some research and it looks to require some org.eclipse.* plugins.

After looking into this, it seems a little daunting. It seems most likely that I would be creating a novel plugin that could be used to automate creation of a new project.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a PDE Project Template for your kind of projects (see  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2092214/1369991). PDE Project Templates are meant to generate plug-in projects, but there are no restrictions on other use cases.