# Java template for a project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is it possible to make creation of (Java) file(s) in Eclipse easier/quicker.

I know there is that "Create new class wizard", but it is slow for my "special" needs...

I have a specific project in which I'm creating new classes often, but the structure for those classes is the same. Let say I want to create class `A`, so I want file `A.java` to be created as

```java
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
    static int solve() {
    }
}
```

and it would be perfect that also `ATest.java` is created for this class, for example

```java
class ATest {
    @Test
    int test1() {
        Assert.assertEquals(0, A.solve());
    }
}
```

or is there such plugin for Eclipse?

Comment: Not sure if its a duplicate, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2092200/877472) looks highly relevant.

Comment: Thanks, I have to check...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can try using [**FastCode**](http://3pintech.com/products/fast-code/installation.htm) Plugin, where you can create new templates as per your requirement. As FastCode plugin supports custom templates, here is an example how to create the above class and test class together:

```
<template name="CREATE_NEW_CLASS">
        <description>Used to Create class in the specified package.</description>
        <allowed-file-names>*.*</allowed-file-names>
        <first-template-item>package</first-template-item>
        <second-template-item>none</second-template-item>
        <additional-parameters>className</additional-parameters>
        <template-body>
            <![CDATA[
            <fc:class type="class" name="${className}" package="${package.name}" project="${package.javaProject}">
            public class ${className} {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                }
                static int solve() {
                }
            }
            </fc:class>
            <fc:class type="test" name="${className}Test" package="${package.name}" project="${package.javaProject}">
            public class ${className}Test {
            @Test
                int test1(){
                    Assert.assertEquals(0, ${className}.solve());
                }
            }
            </fc:class>
        ]]>
    </template-body>
</template>
```

Once you add the template, you need to do import using import option in [template preference page](http://3pintech.com/products/fast-code/templates.htm#colorcodingtemplates) as explained in the document.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to me that FastCode plugin can handle a lot of usefull features that I miss in Eclipse. Thanks you also, that you provided more detailed information how to configure the plugin I'll check that later today.

Comment: I cannot create single template - NPE: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.fastcode.util.VelocityUtil.validateVariablesAndMethods(VelocityUtil.java:402)
 at org.fastcode.preferences.OpenEditTemplateDialog.okPressed(OpenEditTemplateDialog.java:583)

Comment: here is my try (http://i.imgur.com/BoTirBU.png), it's new Eclipse I downloaded just now, full error message is http://pastebin.com/S2M91ZFM

Comment: I also tried to export all templates and later  I was not able to import it back, unfortunatelly very bad piece of software...

Comment: Betlista, Looking at your snapshot, i feel it is just a warning message, still it proceeds further and does export/import templates. Still if there are any issues with the plugin, please contact using contact form  http://3pintech.com/contacts.htm in the website and I am sure they will rectify your issues.

Comment: Ok, I was not clear, when I press whatever button, the template is not created, there is only one option = to cancel template creation...

Comment: I found link for bug-tracker also I'll give it a try it seems like something I requested ;-)

Comment: To use fastcode plugin, you need atleast one java project in your workspace.  Have one and then try creating the templates.  Hope it helps you.

Comment: You may be correct, I tried editing templates without creating project first probably... I'll let you know ;-)

Comment: I created the template, but how can I create the class with the template? I didn't find the option in menu...

Comment: once you create the template through preference page, do export templates. Then u can invoke the template in any editor by using shortcut keys ctrl+alt+shift T, a dialog will appear, there select the template which you have created in the drop down and proceed further.  You can have a look at demo links to be more clear on how to use the templates (http://3pintech.com/products/fast-code/instance-of-class-from-fields.htm) or http://3pintech.com/products/fast-code/templates.htm#instanceclass

Comment: I tried to read that, but instead of shortcut I was trying from menu. I assume I do not need to do export/import as I created template via GUI, but if not working I'll try export/import also (I tried to restart Eclipse when I crteated template)...

Comment: Shortcut works. What is not working well, that I have to invoke the shortcut in editor view (it's not working from package explorer view). I have a problem with default package and there is also warning that "There is no package in /src/main/java /src". Test is also not created currently, but I believe this is what I asked for.

Comment: Once you create template via GUI also export needs to be done, to save that template permanently in your workspace else it will not show your added template.  Next, the templates need to be invoked in editor view. You can check the link how to set default src path in fastcode preference page. http://3pintech.com/products/fast-code/documentation.htm#fastcodeprefpage . You require a src folder and test folder, create one and then invoke the templates. Get back if the issues still exists.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is relatively simple to set up. Open the Project Properties and navigate to the **Java Code Style** > **Code Templates** section. Once there, check the box to enable project-specific settings. The generation template you want is under the **Code** part of the tree; you want **Class Body**. It is probably empty, but click the *Edit...* button to modify it.

[image]

Whatever you enter in the Edit dialog will be inserted between the class' brackets when using the New Class wizard.

There's no way I know of to automatically create another class (the Test in your case). But Eclipse has a JUnit wizard that makes doing so very easy. Just right-click on a class and choose **New** > **Other...** and then find **Junit Test Case** in the list. That wizard will guide you through creating the test class, including selecting the method(s) you want to test.

Note: these instructions set up the template for just the project or projects you select. You could also set up the same thing for your entire workspace Preferences, but doing so provides no way to share that configuration so that the same project checked out into another workspace will use it. I usually recommend making these kinds of settings on a per-project basis.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need an IDE-specific template for that. When I was going through Project Euler, I had a setup like this:

```
public interface Problem {
    public Object solve();
}

public class MyProblem implements Problem {
    @Override
    public Object solve() {
        // do some stuff
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then in your (JUnit?) tests, you could use

```
Assert.assertEquals(expected, myProblemInstance.solve());
```

You can see my implementation [here](https://github.com/thatJavaNerd/ProjectEuler/tree/master/src/net/dean/projecteuler)

---

If you *do* use an IDE template, you won't be able to use a generic `solve()` method, since it is not guaranteed that that class has that method. I would highly recommend using interfaces.